# Animate toggle height from 0 to auto or 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help, I want the toggle buttons to only show and hide the paragraphs but the other contents inside the `div` should remain always visible. Also, the CSS is the same and I am trying to smoothen the transition of the DIV's height when showing and hiding the paragraphs

```js
const toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.toggleButton');
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.paragraph');

toggleButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const paragraph = paragraphs[index];
    paragraph.classList.toggle('hidden');
    paragraph.classList.toggle('visible');

    if (paragraph.classList.contains('visible')) {
      divs[index].style.height = paragraph.scrollHeight + 'px';
    } else {
      divs[index].style.height = '0';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  background: blue;
}

.paragraph {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggleButton">Toggle 1</button>
<div> HI
  <p class="paragraph hidden">Paragraph 1.</p>
</div>

<button class="toggleButton">Toggle 2</button>
<div> Hi
  <p class="paragraph hidden">Paragraph 2.</p>
</div>

<button class="toggleButton">Toggle 3</button>
<div> Hi
  <p class="paragraph hidden">Paragraph 3.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted results in `ReferenceError: toggleButtons is not defined`, and your CSS isn't complete (a class is missing). Also, please explain what you want to do.

Comment: You want the *other contents to be visible* - than, why you use `height: 0;` on the `div` ?

Comment: The transition [doesn't work](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/why-does-the-css-transition-property-not-work-with-display-none) on `display` property. Just apply the `opacity` effect (which is an *animatable* property, as well as `height`).

Comment: @Alexis88 no. One would never want to do (only) that in the context of *accordions*. Opacity might create a fade effect, but the damage of immediately collapsing containers is already achieved. Elements that vertically collapse should open, collapse in a natural, cognitively acceptable way - and that's by animating the height. Not necessarily by fading in-out the content (which might be eventually an add-on). Also in CSS you cannot just *transition height* from `0` to `auto`. There's other methods.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I guess I oversimplified my answer (sorry for that). Actually it depends on *how* the code has been implemented. You can play with `max-height` or `transform: scaleY()` properties, as well as `opacity`, in order the get an accordion effect. There are many ways to do the task (a bunch of them right here in SO).

Comment: @Alexis88 achieving accordions with `max-height` is fundamentally broken since you're forced to assign a magic number as the expanding height. See for example a random link I've found: https://codepen.io/yoelnacho/pen/RPXgYy Is 500 a magic number? Yes. Bug prone? Yes. How does the collapse animation performs? Broken. With a delay.  Then, `transform: scaleY()` is a visual sin.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Not exactly a *"magic number"*, I think. In a real situation, it would be counterproductive to generate an accordion effect that occupies a greater height than the user's device screen. In cases where the total height of the accordion content is greater than the device screen, the value of `max-height` can be `100vh` (or less) and set `overflow-y: auto` for scroll. I just tried that and [it works fine](https://codepen.io/Alexis88/pen/NWEgzvm).

Comment: @Alexis88 good point, for a specific scenario might be sufficient for the decision-making (does not needs additional wrapping DIVs) and clearly *is better* than using a fixed max-height px integer. But in such case you might end up having two scrollbars, the page's one, and the carousels - which again, might just not be a viable solution. Scrollbars *can* be added (if there's really the need) to the grid solution, but not the opposite.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Right, but at this point, it depends on personal preferences. For me, it's unconfortable to have to scroll through a long menu of options using the window's scrollbar, which will end up causing me to find myself in a view of the page that is far below, after closing the menu. Anyway, I liked your solution. Cheers, buddy.

Comment: Just in addition to my previous answer, [it's possible](https://blog.logrocket.com/hide-scrollbar-without-impacting-scrolling-css/) to hide the scrollbar and still doing the scroll. I just implemented it on [my codepen](https://codepen.io/Alexis88/pen/NWEgzvm) and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Animate expand|collapse height using grid-template-columns|rows

`display` property **cannot** be transitioned (animated). Also, the *trick* to transition `max-height` is fundamentally **broken** since it does not work well when collapsing during a defined amount of time; makes use of magic numbers to transition to: `max-height: "big-magic-number"unit;`) causing animation gaps or unwanted scrollbars when using values like `100%|vh`.

**Solution:**
transition (animate) the carousel element using [CSS `grid` and
`grid-template-rows`](https://chriscoyier.net/2022/12/21/things-css-could-still-use-heading-into-2023/#animate-to-auto) from `0fr` to `1fr`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]').forEach(elBtn => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(elBtn.dataset.toggle).classList.toggle("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition: grid-template-rows 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.content.open {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.content-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="#content_1" >Toggle 1</button>
<div> HI
  <div class="content" id="content_1">
    <div class="content-inner">
      1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias labore fuga quia, iste rerum nulla, reprehenderit at quasi id omnis dolorem. Iusto repellendus nemo reiciendis rerum facere maxime dicta. Fugit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" data-toggle="#content_2">Toggle 2</button>
<div> HI
  <div class="content" id="content_2">
    <div class="content-inner">
      2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametIusto repellendus nemo reiciendis rerum facere maxime dicta. Fugit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" data-toggle="#content_3">Toggle 3</button>
<div> HI
  <div class="content" id="content_3">
    <div class="content-inner">
      3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus id similique laboriosam eos perspiciatis aliquam corporis esse veniam ab aspernatur debitis, provident rerum nemo blanditiis! Beatae delectus, provident totam iusto.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
  
<button type="button" data-toggle="#content_3">I also toggle 3.</button>
```

Also, don't use `<p>` as your carousel collapsible element. Animate display-block elements like DIV. `<p>` might be indeed a *display-block* element, but historically served the purpose as a styled content wrapper, and should be used for content and semantics, not as an architectural block, that animates.

Accessibility alert
For simplification-of-answer I missed to, but don't forget to add the needed *A11Y* [Aria attributes](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/examples/accordion/)  and the needed JS code to toggle the `aria-expanded="true"` `"false"` values on click.

Acknowledgments:

- [(FIXED) Chrome bugs - Support transitions/animations on grid-template-columns|rows](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=759665#c19)
- [Nelson Menezes - Animating height auto](https://nemzes.net/posts/animating-height-auto/#the-solutions)
- [Chris Coyer - Animate to `auto`](https://chriscoyier.net/2022/12/21/things-css-could-still-use-heading-into-2023/#animate-to-auto)
- [Stefan Judis - How to animate an element's height using CSS `grid`](https://www.stefanjudis.com/snippets/how-to-animate-height-with-css-grid/)

Comment: Thank you so much it works really well! Will review the links! :)