# Width transition from 0 to auto on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the button that shows icon after hovering.

Now, the button seems to be stuck in hover when you stay ~2sec in hover state

Can anyone fix this? And try to make it smoother?

GIF: [image: bro]

```css
.button {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #323232;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
}

.button-text-container {
  order: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: max-width;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 0;
}

.button-icon-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.button:hover .button-text-container {
  max-width: 1275px;
}

.button-text-container>span {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="button-icon-container">icon</div>
  <div class="button-text-container"><span>test</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient?

Comment: do you want the gradient code included?

Comment: https://codepen.io/du_cc/pen/abQqOvR

Comment: Please put a runnable snippet into your question which shows the problem. And please describe what you want the animation to look like - 'it sucks' doesn't tell us what you are aiming for.

Comment: have example snippet in the post?

Comment: @close-voter, the snippet is present in the question FYI. Just collapsed. Look closer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Animate `auto` height/width  using CSS `grid`

The problem in animating to `max-width/height: "big-magic-number"unit;` lies exactly in the number being *magic* and *big*. Takes time to revert to `0` during a defined transition period.

Transitioning a carousel using `max-width` / `max-height` is flawed and broken by design.

#### Animate width to *"auto"* solution:

A better solution would be using CSS `grid` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76608716/383904), where basically the animation transitions from `0fr` to `1fr`

```css
.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #323232;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
}

.button-slide {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0fr;
  transition: grid-template-columns 0.4s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button:hover .button-slide {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.button-slide-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <span class="button-icon">❤️</span>
  <div class="button-slide">
    <div class="button-slide-inner"><span>Heart space</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To recap, use `grid-template-columns` to animate *"width"*, and `grid-template-rows` to animate *"height"*.

Comment: This is a better solution.

Comment: @Ongyj888 you're very welcome. Make sure to read the associated link, there's more info and the kudos, resources for the original idea.

Comment: this have a flaw, if I insert space in the button, it will break words. I have tried             word-wrap: normal !important;
but still unsolved

Comment: Resolved using   `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @ducc yes, good catch `white-space: nowrap` is used to prevent words wrapping into a new line. Glad you resolved this pretty quickly on your own

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
max-width: 1275px;
```

Basically, what happens during transitions is based on the set duration (in your case, 1s), the transition property value keeps changing. So in your case, `max-width` gets changed from 0 to 1275 over 1s period.

If the transition ends prematurely, that is, if you move your mouse out before 1s, the reverse transition happens, that is, `max-width` starts decreasing from whatever value at that point (say, 700) to 0 over the exact same duration that changed it from 0 to 700. It will be less than 1s because you ended it prematurely.

And because in your code, the visual change is only visible for the initial brief duration, you think you experience that the more you have your mouse inside the element, the more "delay" you get.

You can visualize what's happening to `max-width` by changing your transition property from `max-width` to `width`.

```css
.button {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #323232;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
}

.button-text-container {
  order: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: fit-content;
  width: 0;
}

.button-icon-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.button:hover .button-text-container {
  width: 1275px;
}

.button-text-container>span {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="button-icon-container">icon</div>
  <div class="button-text-container"><span>test</span></div>
</div>
```

So, the solution is to not transition `max-width` (I don't know why you used it) and use magic numbers but instead, use a better solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76677717/3930247).

Comment: I need to use max-width because width:fit-content is inanimateable

Comment: so do you have any workarounds for fit-content but animatable?

Comment: @Ongyj888 no, don't use `max-width` for transitions. That trick is broken by design and hard to control.