# Is there a way to target an element that shares the same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a container with text that I want to show a read more/read less function that when clicked, displays or hides text. The problem is, I have about 10 of these containers on the same page and when I click a read more in one of the containers it affects every container on the page. I need the read more / read less function to only happen on the container where I click.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var productDescription = $('.summary'),
    productReadMore = $('.description-read-more'),
    currentHeight = productDescription.height(),
    autoHeight = productDescription.css('height', 'auto').height(),
    showMoreText = 'Read More',
    showLessText = 'Read Less';

  productDescription.css('height', currentHeight);

  productReadMore.click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      productDescription.removeClass('active');
      productDescription.height(currentHeight).animate({
        height: currentHeight
      }, 0);
      productReadMore.find('.text_more').html(showMoreText);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      productDescription.addClass('active');
      productDescription.height(currentHeight).animate({
        height: autoHeight
      }, 0);
      productReadMore.find('.text_more').html(showLessText);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="summary">
  <p><strong>Description:</strong></p>
  <p>initial content</p>
  <p>more content</p>
</div>
<div class="description-read-more"><span class="text_more">Read More</span></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're already a member for over 8y, by now you should be accustomed to [code snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  [edit] to create a [mcve].

Comment: You use jQuery. Why do you use `height` (specially in this responsive era) when jQuery provides out of the box https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: *"Why doe this work on one when I want it to work on more than one"* - usually involves in forEaching (jQuery's `.each()`) your set... or i.e: getting the `height` on that element's click.

Comment: Also, why don't you wrap the `button` and the contents inside a common parent? That way you loop the parents only.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I set a height of 80px on .summary so some of the content shows. I don't want to hide all content and show all content like a toggle does.

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Add a listener to the `document` for which the handler only works if the event target (the element that was clicked on) has a `read-more` class.

I would then group the section that needs to be displayed within the section that's triggering its opening/closing. From there grab the `summary` element of the clicked button using [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), find the section with the `text-more` class, and then [`toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle) it.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.read-more', function () {
  $(this)
    
    // Find the closest summary element
    .closest('.summary')
    
    // Find its text-more element
    .find('.text-more')
    
    // Toggle its class
    .toggle();
});
```

```css
.read-more { border: 0; }
.text-more { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="summary">
  <p>Section 1</p>
  <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
  <section class="text-more">
    <p>Section 1 more text</p>
  </section>
</section>
<section class="summary">
  <p>Section 2</p>
  <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
  <section class="text-more">
    <p>Section 2 more text</p>
  </section>
</section>
<section class="summary">
  <p>Section 3</p>
  <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
  <section class="text-more">
    <p>Section 3 more text</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

If you *don't* want to group the markup together you can use data attributes to indicate which section should be toggled instead.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.read-more', function () {
  
  // Find the id attached to the summary section
  const id = $(this).closest('.summary').data('id');
  
  // Use the id to create a selector that matches
  // the text-more section with that id
  const selector = `.text-more[data-id=${id}]`;
  
  // Use the selector to find that elenent
  const $text = $(document).find(selector);
  
  // Toggle it
  $text.toggle();
});
```

```css
.read-more { border: 0; }
.text-more { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="summary" data-id="1">
  <p>Section 1</p>
  <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
</section>
<section class="text-more" data-id="1">
  <p>Section 1 more text</p>
</section>
<section class="summary" data-id="2">
  <p>Section 2</p>
  <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
</section>
<section class="text-more" data-id="2">
  <p>Section 2 more text</p>
</section>
<section class="summary" data-id="3">
  <p>Section 3</p>
  <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
</section>
<section class="text-more" data-id="3">
  <p>Section 3 more text</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Cheers @mplungjan. Much more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

One idea, without using JavaScript, would be to [animate to auto height using CSS `grid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76608716/383904) and use a checkbox (or radio) input for the toggling.
In this example I'm using the `:has()`, but to support Firefox (2023. ATM)
you can place the input in the parent wrapper and reference sibling elements using `~`.

```css
.additional-outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition: grid-template-rows 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.additional-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.more {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #0bf;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.more::before {
  content: "Read more";
}

.summary:has(input:checked) .more::before {
  content: "Read less";
}

.summary:has(input:checked) .additional-outer {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="summary">
  <h3>Some title</h3>
  <div class="initial">
    Initial. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt iste, ut vero voluptatem exercitationem dolorem minus facilis natus, officiis porro reiciendis aspernatur ex quae enim tenetur quia dicta veniam amet.
  </div>
  <div class="additional-outer">
    <div class="additional-inner">
      Additional. Repellendus accusantium doloremque et, iusto deserunt alias, cumque totam libero officiis voluptate sunt quisquam nam, consequuntur ipsa placeat nihil. Labore at, quaerat.
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="more"><input type="checkbox" hidden></label>
</div>

<div class="summary">
  <h3>Some other description</h3>
  <div class="initial">
    Initial. Adipisicing elit. Placeat illum repudiandae repellat ex accusantium neque quibusdam pariatur aut dignissimos assumenda aliquam, ducimus asperiores consequuntur sint quaerat quia porro voluptatem. Facere!
  </div>
  <div class="additional-outer">
    <div class="additional-inner">
      Additional. Temporibus nisi ut dolorum corrupti officia unde similique, atque aliquid mollitia, rem dolores, dignissimos molestias qui enim, quae repellendus repellat asperiores consectetur..
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="more"><input type="checkbox" hidden></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery when you make a search of the kind of `$(someselector)` then all the items matching that selector apply. Hence, for example, `productReadMore` is defined as

```
productReadMore = $('.description-read-more')
```

and that applies for all elements having this class. Which is good when you call the `.click()` function, because it attaches a `click` event for all elements having this class. However, inside the function you need to differentiate and use `$(this)` rather than `productReadMore` to identify the item to change rather than change all items.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var productDescription = $('.summary'),
    productReadMore = $('.description-read-more'),
    currentHeight = productDescription.height(),
    autoHeight = productDescription.css('height', 'auto').height(),
    showMoreText = 'Read More',
    showLessText = 'Read Less';

  productDescription.css('height', currentHeight);

  productReadMore.click(function() {
    productDescription = $(this).prev();
    currentHeight = productDescription.height();
    autoHeight = productDescription.css('height', 'auto').height();

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      productDescription.removeClass('active');
      productDescription.height(currentHeight).animate({
        height: currentHeight
      }, 0);
      $(this).find('.text_more').html(showMoreText);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      productDescription.addClass('active');
      productDescription.height(currentHeight).animate({
        height: autoHeight
      }, 0);
      $(this).find('.text_more').html(showLessText);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="summary">
  <p><strong>Description:</strong></p>
  <p>initial content</p>
  <p>more content</p>
</div>
<div class="description-read-more"><span class="text_more">Read More</span></div>
<div class="summary">
  <p><strong>Description:</strong></p>
  <p>initial content</p>
  <p>more content</p>
</div>
<div class="description-read-more"><span class="text_more">Read More</span></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```